# Java - Noughts and Crosses/Tic Tac Toe game winning algorithm not working

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Recently starting college, we are being taught how to program in Java. If we wanted to for a challenge it was suggested to us to try and make a noughts and crosses game from a broken piece of code.

I managed to get the program running fine, the X or O is displayed on the board and checking to see if there is three of the same symbol in a row or column works fine, however for some reason if it checks to see if there is three in a row on any line it doesn't work and I cannot figure out why. I have asked friends and they don't see why it isn't working either (probably something obvious which I missed out).

To check if either the X or O has won, I created another 2D array which puts a 1 in the location of an X on the board and a -1 if the location on the board is an O. It then checks to see if there is either a -1 or 1 on the rows, columns and diagonals. If there is a -1, a 1 is added to the counter for O or if it is 1, a 1 is added to counter for X.

At the end of the function, it checks to see if the counter for O or X is equal to three, if it is, it returns true if not it returns false.

Here is the code (it is some 315 lines of code, thought it would be easier to copy and paste the whole program so you could see if I am going wrong anywhere else, scroll down to the bottom for `checkXOrOHasWon` function where the broken part is)  :

the code is:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoughtsAndCrosses {

static int count[][] = new int[4][4];
static char board[][] = new char[4][4];
static String playerOneName;
static String playerTwoName;

static int xCoord;
static int yCoord;
static int noOfMoves;
static int checkO = 0;
static int checkX = 0;

static boolean validMove;
static boolean gameHasBeenWon;
static boolean gameHasBeenDrawn;

static char currentSymbol;

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialiseBoard();
    System.out.println("What is the name of player one? ");
    playerOneName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("What is the name of player two? ");
    playerTwoName = sc.next();

    currentSymbol = 'X';

    // Play a game
    noOfMoves = 0;
    gameHasBeenDrawn = false;
    gameHasBeenWon = false;

    System.out.println();
    displayBoard(board);
    System.out.println("\n" + playerOneName + " starts playing " + currentSymbol);
    System.out.println();

    do { //Play until a player wins or the game is drawn
        do { //Get a valid move

            xCoord = getX();
            yCoord = getY();
            System.out.println("");
            validMove = checkValidMove(xCoord, yCoord, board);
            if (!validMove) {
                System.out.println("Coordinates invalid, please try again");
            } // end if
        } while (!validMove);

        board[xCoord][yCoord] = currentSymbol;
        displayBoard(board);
        gameHasBeenWon = checkXOrOHasWon(board);
        noOfMoves++;

        if (!gameHasBeenWon) {
            // Check if maximum number of allowed moves has been reached
            if (noOfMoves == 9) {
                gameHasBeenDrawn = true;
            } else {
                if (currentSymbol == 'X') {
                    currentSymbol = 'O';
                    System.out.println(playerTwoName + "'s turn");
                } else {
                    currentSymbol = 'X';
                    System.out.println(playerOneName + "'s turn");
                } // end if/else
            } // end if/else
        } // end if
    } while (!gameHasBeenWon && !gameHasBeenDrawn);

    //Display result
    if (gameHasBeenWon) {
        if ('X' == currentSymbol) {
            System.out.println(playerOneName + " congratulations you win!");

        } else {
            System.out.println(playerTwoName + " congratulations you win!");

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("A draw this time!");
    }
} //end method main

public static void initialiseBoard() {

}

public static void displayBoard(char[][] board) {
    int row;
    int column;
    System.out.println("  | 1 2 3 ");
    System.out.println("--+-------");

    for (row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
        System.out.print(row + " | ");
        for (column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {
            System.out.print(board[column][row] + " ");
        } // end column
        System.out.println();
    } // end row
} // end method displayBoard

public static int getX() {
    System.out.println("Please enter an X coordinate");
    xCoord = sc.nextInt();

    return xCoord;
}

public static int getY() {
    System.out.println("Please enter an Y coordinate");
    yCoord = sc.nextInt();

    return yCoord;
}

public static boolean checkValidMove(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, char[][] board) {
    ////

    if (xCoordinate > board.length || yCoordinate > board.length || xCoordinate == 0 || yCoordinate == 0 || xCoordinate == 4 || yCoordinate == 4) {
        validMove = false;
    } else {
        validMove = true;
    }

    if (currentSymbol == 'O') {
        count[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] = -1;

    } else if (currentSymbol == 'X') {
        count[xCoordinate][yCoordinate] = 1;
    }

    return validMove;

} // end method checkValidMove

//THIS PART HERE IT SEEMS TO BE BROKEN FOR SOME REASON

public static boolean checkXOrOHasWon(char[][] board) {
    //ALL OF THE ROWS DON'T WORK
    //row 1
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[i][1] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;
        }
        if (count[i][1] == 1) {
            checkX = checkX + 1;
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }
    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }
    //row 2

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[i][2] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;
        }
        if (count[i][2] == 1) {
            checkX = checkX + 1;
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }
    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }
    //row 3
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[i][3] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;
        }
        if (count[i][3] == 1) {
            checkX = checkX + 1;
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }
    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }

    //col 1
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[1][i] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;

        }
        if (count[1][i] == 1) {

            checkX = checkX + 1;
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }

    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }

    //col 2
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[2][i] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;

        }
        if (count[2][i] == 1) {

            checkX = checkX + 1;
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }

    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }

    //col 3
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[3][i] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;

        }
        if (count[3][i] == 1) {

            checkX = checkX + 1;
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }

    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }

    //diag 1
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (count[i][i] == -1) {
            checkO = checkO + 1;
            break;
        }
        if (count[i][i] == 1) {

            checkX = checkX + 1;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }

    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }

    //diag 2
    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            if (count[i][j - 1] == -1) {
                checkO = checkO + 1;
                break;
            }
            if (count[i][j - 1] == 1) {

                checkX = checkX + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (checkO != 3) {
        checkO = 0;
    }

    if (checkX != 3) {
        checkX = 0;
    }

    if (checkX == 3 || checkO == 3) {
        gameHasBeenWon = true;
    } else {
        checkO = 0;
        checkX = 0;
        gameHasBeenWon = false;

    }

    return gameHasBeenWon;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Can you add the state of board (with 3 Xs or 3 Os) which is not giving output as expected?

Comment: You pass board to your check method. Your check method only uses count. Where is count filled?

Comment: When checking the code again only the columns work now and not the diagonal which was before. This is the column:http://postimg.org/image/7sx45g5cl/. This is the diagonal: http://postimg.org/image/eknj8auc5/ and this is the row:http://postimg.org/image/acsqzjswl/

Answer (score 0):

> if it checks to see if there is three in a row on any line it doesn't
>   work and I cannot figure out why.

The code is only testing for checkX or checkY exactly equal to 3 (or not equal to 3), but it's potentially making them total more than 3 in cases where they were 1 or 2 in a previous check.

The simplest fix for your `checkXOrOHasWon()` method is to replace all these blocks (for both checkX and checkO):

```
if (checkX != 3) {
  checkX = 0;
}
```

with this kind of statement instead:

```
if (checkX == 3) {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the value of `checkX` and `check0`  after every row and col check. So, even if it's win, you are progressing to check other row or col which is not needed.

You should return true at the place where you are currently checking `!=3`.

Besides, other tips/changes:
1. You don't need a 4x4 array, you can do with a 3x3, just make use of the indexes correctly.
2. You can make the `CheckXandO()` method modular, by creating `checkRow` and `checkCol` methods and call them in  loop from that method, will reduce the lines of code in your program.

Comment: When I change all the if statement blocks to what gknicker above suggested (aswell as including O), at the end it comes up with missing return statement? (probably over looking something really obvious)

Comment: at the very end... it will be `return false` as none of the win criterias were satisfied..

Comment: Oh missed that!. However now when I run it, it does this:http://postimg.org/image/s03fl1a4j/. Really confused why this isn't working. Also I would make the CheckXandO (was one of the first things I did) however we apparently not allowed to for some reason and must keep the functions and procedures they put it and not add or get rid of any.

Comment: I'm really stumped as to why this isn't working. Change the if statement blocks to check if it is equal to 3 and return true if it is but it returns true regardless of the score?